# saving checkboxes value in plugin admin

Tags: plugins

I basically want to save options from check boxes and want to do it without having to click on Save button but save the option automatically if the user clicks on the check boxes.

[image]

This is how I'm saving it:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(evt) {
            $.post(ajaxurl, {

                action:             'save_checkbox_options',                    
                nonce:              $('#ajax_options_param_nonce').text(),   
                checkbox_id:        $(this).attrib('id'),                       
                post_checkbox_value: $(this).is(':checked')                 

            }, function(response) {             
                //To do after resposne                  
            });

        });

function ajax_save_checkbox_options() {
        // Verify that the incoming request is coming with the security nonce
        if( wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], 'ajax_options_param_nonce' ) ) {



            if( update_option( $_POST['checkbox_id'], 'checkbox_power_options', $checkbox_power_options ) ) {
                die( '1' );
            } else {
                die( '0' );
            } 

        } else {


            die( '-1' );

        }

     }
```

Checkbox structure:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_box_power_options_1" name="check_boxpower_options" value="1"' . checked( 1, get_option( 'checkbox_power_options' ), false ) .'>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_box_power_options_2" name="check_boxpower_options" value="2"' . checked( 2, get_option( 'checkbox_power_options' ), false ) .'>
...
echo '<span id="ajax_checkbox_nonce" class="hidden">' . wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_checkbox_nonce' ) . '</span>';
```

This is how I'm calling the script:

```
 wp_register_script( 'post-checkboxes-admin-script', plugins_url( dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/js/admin.js' ) );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'post-checkboxes-admin-script' );
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work. Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: Did you try taking a look to the AJAX response? I'm, not sure you're using the nonce correctly.

Comment: Please make correction to: $(this).attr('id'), there is no attrib keyword in jQuery.